# core-header-pannel "waterfall-tall" polymer won't appear

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I understand that the problem is likely related to the core-header-pannel parent not having a height.

> Important: The core-header-panel will not display if its parent does not have a height.

This works fine:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    core-header-panel {
        height: 100%;
    }       
</style>    

<body unresolved>
   <core-header-panel>
      <div class="core-header">standard</div>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </core-header-panel>
</body>
```

However, when I try to change the core-header-pannel to mode "waterfall-tall", then the header panel does not show.

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    core-header-panel.tall{
        height: 100%;
    }       
</style>    

<core-header-panel mode = "waterfall-tall">
   <div class="core-header">waterfall-tall</div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</core-header-panel>
```

During the course of my "experiments" I've referenced both https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-header-panel and https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/demo.html

After viewing various StackOverflow questions I think that somehow the `body` is now covering the `header-pannel`, because I'm no longer explicitly setting the height. FYI, I'm totally new to HTML and web development. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

To be clear, my questions are:

- The parent element of the `core-header-panel` is the `body` correct?
- Am I referencing my `<core-header-panel mode = "waterfall-tall">`  in my `<style>` section properly?
- How can I get this darn header pannel to appear?

**update edit:**

OK, I found a solution through experimentation with the demo.html of `core-header-panel`. It works fine on my local host, ie, the header collapses and expands how I expect it should. However, when I paste into jsbin, then I do not get the collapsing effect that I want.

http://jsbin.com/cufefi/1/edit

I think this is due to the utilization of `px` in the `<style>` section, but I'm not sure.

Another question: My imports are relative, so how can `jsbin` resolve the imports?

**second update edit:**

The behaviour is the same with or without the imports, which implies to me that the imports are not resolved, and this is why the behaviour is different when compared to the behaviour on my local host.

Comment: You need to provide absolute paths in `jsbin`, as polymer is not available as a library yet. Just replace your `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">` with `<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here you lost the < body > tag, just before the core-header-panel tag. Could be this the error?

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    core-header-panel.tall{
        height: 100%;
    }       
</style>    

<core-header-panel mode = "waterfall-tall">
   <div class="core-header">waterfall-tall</div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</core-header-panel>
```